# Degeneracy of the analytic center of a set of linear inequalities

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a question about the degeneracy of [the analytic center of a set of linear inequalities](http://www.ee.ucla.edu/ee236b/lectures/geom.pdf).

When the set of linear inequalities is degenerate, I guess that the analytic center would also be degenerate.

I think that this is an example

$$ 
\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\leq 4\\ 3x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\leq 6 \end{cases} 
$$

I guess people have worked on this before and I hope some references could be pointed out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper: [A Surface of Analytic Centers and Primal-Dual Infeasible-Interior-Point Algorithms for Linear Programming](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/3690111) provides the answer to this question.